# Select Specific Text Using Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, delimiter

I am trying to grab certain text using a scanner and delimiter but I keep failing.

Sample from from file:

> CROSSPLANE_AXIS=X
>
> DEPTH_AXIS=Depth
>
> INPLANE_AXIS_DIR=GUN_TARGET
>
> CROSSPLANE_AXIS_DIR=LEFT_RIGHT
>
> DEPTH_AXIS_DIR=UP_DOWN
>
> ENERGY=6.00
>
> NOMINAL_DMAX=13.00
>
> SSD=1000.00
>
> SCD=450.00
>
> BLOCK=0
>
> WEDGE=App25x25

```
public static Double energy;
for (int i = 0; i < lengthOfFiles; i++) {
                Scanner readAndStore = new Scanner(content);
                int j = 0;

                while (readAndStore.hasNextLine()) {

                     if (readAndStore.hasNext("ENERGY=")) {
                        readAndStore.useDelimiter("=");
                        energy = readAndStore.nextDouble();
                        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As all of your lines are the same format it would be easier to

```
 // read all lines
 while (readAndStore.hasNextLine()) {

     String line = readAndStore.readLine ();


     // split using =
     String [] words = line.split ("=");     // assuming you are going to parse all lines

     if (words[0].equals ("ENERGY")) {
         energy = Double.parseDouble (words[1]);
     }
```

Comment: I tried your code and it worked but it also threw off some data values I was reading in the file in code that followed. The code I listed is a header and data that was collected is listed as x and y values separated by spaces.

Comment: I will have to play around with the code. Thank you very much

Comment: Sure you may have to adjust based upon your real data, but the flow should be better than before.